# How to correct play RAW audio files with one Instance of MediaPlayer?

Tags: android, media-player, audio

I don't think what is good but it's works.

I want know is it rigth what i do?

I have 2 files tick.wav and tock.wav wich must be played by timer tick or tock. setLooping not good because i need play by timer init.

So i try two methods:

**First**

I have variable MediaPlayer mp;

When i need play tick i call `mp=MediaPlayer.create(context,tickID)`, when i need play tock i call `mp=MediaPlayer.create(contenxt,tockID)`

When i call mp.start();

Some time it's work good and i hear tick and tock, but then i start getting errors from mediaplayer. I think this because previous instance of MediaPlayer is still playing file.

**Second**

So i do next: i create two variables

```
tickPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(tickID);
```

and

```
tockplayer=MediaPlayer.create(tockID);
```

and then i need tock i call `tockPlayer.start()` when i need tick i call `tickplayer.start()`

I't works, but (always exists but) what me do if files will be more than 2, maybe 100?
Create array of mediaplayers like `Vector<MediaPlayer> mpPlayers`?
And call needed? I think it's eat my memory quickly.

So target is: i need correct playing files with shortime reaction of mediaplayer from RAW soruce, how ca i do what?

Answer (score 0):

May be you don't need Vector to store media files, I think you can use java reflection to get information about "raw" resources as raw is static class from R.java.

And are you stopping media player. tickPlayer.stop().